# I am new to pandas Data frame. i am getting this error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an error from this code:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

The code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel("test123.xlsx")
print(df)
subone = df["F1"] + df["I1"]
print(subone)
```

The Excel File mentioned:

```
   sl no name  F1  F2  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  I1  I2
0      1  abc   0  95         NaN         NaN  10  54
1      2  def  10  88         NaN         NaN  22  21
2      3  ghi  52  44         NaN         NaN  33  21
3      4  jkl  65  55         NaN         NaN  54  21
4      5  bgm  **AB**  25         NaN         NaN  65  23
```

Comment: it looks like you have one row F1=**AB** and I1=65 which you try to add in  `df["F1"] + df["I1"]` . Depending on what you want to do you either have to replace the string with an int or convert the int to a string with `str()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concat two columns

```
subone = df["F1"].astype(str) + df["l1"].astype(str)
print(subone)
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply. i have tried above mentioned method. but its concatenate both columns like below. its not adding.                                                                                               0     010
1    1022
2    5233
3    6554
4    AB65
dtype: object